# Difference between "bug" "issue" "problem"

Tags: word-choice

Any ideas what are the difference is of the three words?

Thanks for answer

Comment: There is great overlap in the meanings. None of the words are particularly precise. The difference, where it exists, is in the nuances: **A bug** is informal. It implies a malfunction in a machine or system: it is the equivalent of a disease in a creature or plant; **an issue** is an apparent defect and the word implies that the defect should be addressed; **a problem** is (i) a defect that either has (or appears at first glance to have) no immediate solution and/or explanation or (ii) a circumstance that will cause difficulties.

Comment: @Greybeard Wow thank you very much honestly.  Now it has become clear to me.  If you want please reply so I can mark it as solved.

Comment: In addition to what @Greybeard said, "bug" also has a connotation of being a *minor* problem or issue, the exception being if someone goes out of their way to describe it as "major," "huge," etc. If something is described as having a lot of "bugs," that can also be inferred as major, much like actual bugs (i.e., insects), one being generally only a minor problem that you can solve quickly and easily with a stomp of your foot but many possibly adding up to a major problem requireing an exterminator.

Comment: @Cascabel The OP has 99 reputation and does not seem to be promoting anything...

Comment: In corporate America, any time you want to post your boss about a problem, you substitute the word *issue* as the neutral equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is great overlap in the meanings.

**Bug** starts as

> OED

I. An insect or other arthropod.

> 1 *Any small insect or larva that is considered to be a pest. Also more widely (now chiefly U.S.): any insect or other small arthropod (e.g. a spider or centipede),*
>
> 1594   Hester's Pearle of Pract. i. xxxii. 14   *This medecine caused many times, a certaine blacke bugge, or worme to come forth which had many legs, & was quicke.*

It becomes in extended use

> 3. derogatory. **A contemptible or dishonest person. In later use chiefly: an annoying person; a pest, a nuisance.**
>
> [1771   T. Smollett Humphry Clinker I. 225   **[One writer] who presumed to make strictures upon one of his performances, he holds as a bug in criticism, whose stench is more offensive than his sting.]**

The idea of a pest then developed further:

> 4. colloquial (originally U.S.).**a. A person with an obsessive or enthusiastic interest in something. Frequently with modifying word indicating the object of obsession or enthusiasm.**
>
> 1841   Congress. Globe June 133   *Mr. Alford of Georgia warned the ‘tariff bugs’ of the South that..he would read them out of church.*

The next development was the extension from insects to bacteria/germs:

> 6. colloquial (originally U.S.).a. **A harmful microorganism or virus; a germ.**
>
> 1885   Trans. Mich. State Med. Soc. 9 177   *He..Knew all the mysteries of bacterian skill, /And never let a micrococcus grow / When he had ample power the bug to kill.*

This extended to machines:

> 5. Originally U.S. a. **A defect or fault in a machine (esp. an electrical or electronic one), or in a process, etc.**
>
> 1875   Operator 15 Aug. 5/1   The biggest ‘bug’ yet has been discovered in the U.S. Hotel Electric Annunciator.
>
> 1952   Rev. Electronic Digital Computers (Amer. Inst. Electr. Engineers) 18/2   The week we spent in getting the last bug out of our instruction program was an investment we hated to have to make.

Now we see the modern meaning of the word: something small that is a nuisance as it causes something else to function badly, be it a person or a machine.

---

**Issue** starts in the 14th century with the verb “to issue”

> **I. To emerge, arise; to come out or come forth.**

An issue can be anything from the issue of water from a spring to the issue of children from a woman. Issue thus described anything that resulted from something appearing.

The significant meaning however was a legal one that was first recorded in the 15th century

> **14. A matter which remains to be decided; a significant matter for debate or discussion.**
>
> 1429–30   Rolls of Parl.: Henry VI (Electronic ed.) Parl. Sept. 1429 §30. m. 9   *What issue that is triable by inquest in the said forest and hundreds..that it be tried by inquest of the corps of the said shire.*

In this meaning “an issue” – that which came out of an action by someone - was almost synonymous with “a cause”, and that demanded some action by the court or anyone else wishing to rectify the matter.

Thus we have: something upon which action is required.

---

Finally, we have

**Problem**, which was originally: **†1.a. A puzzle; a riddle; an enigmatic statement.** Now obsolete.

which became

**3.a. A difficult or demanding question; (now, more usually) a matter or situation regarded as unwelcome, harmful, or wrong and needing to be overcome; a difficulty.**

Thus, none of the words are particularly precise. The difference, where it exists, is in the nuances:

A **bug** is informal. It implies a malfunction in a machine or system: it is the equivalent of a disease in a creature or plant.

An **issue** is an apparent defect and the word implies that the defect should be addressed.

A **problem** is (i) a defect that either has (or appears at first glance to have) no immediate solution and/or explanation or (ii) a circumstance that will cause difficulties.

Comment: Note that a system may have issues or problems that are not bugs. In the IT sense "bug" applies where a system or application is not operating as intended, usually caused by an error in the implementation, but "bug" does not apply where the intended behaviour is causing unexpected problems.